# Mysql configuration file permission

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mysql

in etc/mysql/my.cnf my.cnf is blocked in 777 permission and when I change it to any other permission it will stay at 777 and will not change.

The content of `my.cnf` is:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Same for `mysqld.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` any permission that I give to `mysqld.cnf` other than `777` will make that MySQL failed to restart.

And I got this error:

```
mysql warning world writable config file etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf is ignored
```

What I understand is that any config in mysqld.cnf will be ignored because it's 777 but if I change its permission to any other one MySQL will stops.

What should I do to modify the permission of those 2 files without MySQL stops working.

ps: MySQL error.log and mysql.log are empty and never get anything on them, I think it's normal because they're enabled in MySQL config file but this file is ignored because it has permission set to 777.